# Making multiple background images scalable using CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, css

I know there are a ton of questions on here related to this, but nothing that directly solved my situation.  Here's the site I am working on:

http://ledvideowall.net

As you re-size the browser window width smaller, the background images behind "LED Video Wall rental and sales" and "CONTACT US" scale down, but the height of the containers stay fixed, creating the extra white space in between those elements.

Is there an easy way to set the starting height of those two elements but also have the height scale along with the width while keeping the aspect ratio of those images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wouldn't it be easier to make the contact us bit using a div layered over the top with its transparency set to 50% rather than try to resize 3 images in unison

Comment: Yes, it would.  I already started working on such a solution using one background image and 2 floating DIVs.  :)